# Improve efficiency of PostgreSQL Query - One to Many, Count is 1

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, group-by

I would like to improve the efficiency of the following query, if possible:

```
SELECT * FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_items oi
ON o.id = oi.order_id
WHERE o.fulfilled = false
AND o.id NOT IN (SELECT order_id
    FROM order_items
    WHERE sku = '011111'
    GROUP BY order_id
    HAVING COUNT(order_id) = 1)
```

There is a one to many relationship between the orders and order_items tables (o.id = oi.order_id).

The goal is to select all of the information from two tables, with the following conditions:

1. The order has not been fulfilled (orders.fulfilled = false).
2. Exclude all of the orders that have exactly one order item with an SKU of '011111' (oi.sku like '011111').

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure that condition 2 meets what you have in the query. What you currently have is where sku does not equal 011111 and the count equals 1. Presumably this should either be not in with equals or count(order_id)>1? What indexes do you have? What is the relative frequency of sku's in your table, etc. What does explain say?

Comment: @JohnBarça - You are totally right about the query being incorrect. My first thought would be to take the approach of the o.id not being in the inner select statement and change that inner statement to "where sku LIKE '011111'". Thanks. I will research the items you asked about (indexes and explain). Regarding the frequency of SKUs, every order item has an SKU. Most orders have 1 order item. Very few have more than three order items. Does that answer your question about frequency, or were you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, not in would probably be clearer, could you edit the question please. I am assuming you have an index on sku and orderid, at the very least? LIKE queries are a performance killer if you have a leading wildcard, but if you change this to be not in and sku='0111111' you should be ok.

Comment: @JohnBarça - Indexes: "orders_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id) and "order_items_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id). So, just the id columns.

Comment: Does the sku have to be a string with a leading 0? Either way it should probably be indexed. You could also index fulfilled, although it is probably not very selective, being just a binary field, although if a small percentage is not fulfilled, and index would help you find those very quickly. As user17130 has said, you might want to keep a separate value for count by sku, as doing a count every time is quite inefficient. Sorry, lots of options :D

Comment: 1) Does `order_items` have a primary kye? (i suppose it does) 2) do you also want to select orders with zero items, or just the ones with more-than-one item ?

Comment: @wildplasser - 1. order_items does have a primary key (id). 2. I would prefer not to select the orders with no order items. Those are pretty rare, so I'm not particularly concerned about it, but if it can be done without increasing the complexity of the query much (or if it already happening in the current query), then yes.

Answer (score 0):

IN can be slower , modified the query to use inner join

```
select * from orders o
inner join order_items oi
on o.id = oi.order_id
and o.fulfilled = false
inner join( select order_id
    from order_items
    where sku != '011111'
    group by order_id
    having count(order_id) = 1) T
on T.order_id = oi.id
```

Answer (score 0):

`count(whatever)` usually will force a full table scan (because it has no idea  how many orders there are grouped by order_items and you can not create an index on an aggregate),  unless there is another clause that can use an index. Most likely a sku not equaling something will not be selective enough (I'm guessing you have a lot skus.) You can look at the `explain` output and you probably see a full table scan in the `IN` part of you query.

If thats the case then you have the option of caching the count data and then indexing it through a [trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-trigger.html) function that updates a `current_count` column every time an order is placed or fulfilled. Or, you could cache a query that kept tracked of the count (say if the information does not need to refreshed very much.)

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that an order can't have more than one item with the same sku on the same order?
Can we assume that you can't have an order with no items?

If so, writing the opposite might be faster.  The query below finds all orders that have any sku other than '011111'.  Also, correlated subqueries are usually faster than non-correlated subqueries (although optimizers are smart enough to rewrite this a lot of the time).  Exists clauses are usually faster than an in clause since the engine can exit before looking through all of the subquery rows.

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders o
 INNER JOIN order_items oi
    ON o.id = oi.order_id
 WHERE o.fulfilled = false
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                 FROM order_items oi2
                WHERE o.order_id = oi2.order_id
                  AND sku != '011111')
```